# Meaning of tmux shortcuts

Tags: linux, terminal, tmux

I understand some of tmux shortcuts: (prefixed by `<C-b>`)

- `d`: detach
- `c`: create
- `n`: next
- `p`: previous

But I don't understand the meaning of splitting pane shortcuts (`"` and `%`). These buttons are also far from home row. This makes it difficult for me to remember.

What is the meaning of the splitting pane shortcuts? (`"` and `%`)

Comment: Have you tried them? What happened?

Comment: @larsks I know what they do. I mean they are hard to remember since they are not mnemonics like other shortcuts. I expect tmux devs to have some meaning behind the shortcuts to make it easy to remember

Comment: I guess you could pretend that `%` represents two things with a line between them, but honestly a lot of people just remap those keys to `-` and `|`, which are intuitively much more obvious.